# Generate downloadable link to a file and automatically initiate download

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Users generate files on my node js server by pressing a button on a web page.
The server then creates a .zip file.
I want to expose this zip file so that it can be downloaded automatically on to the users' client.
Once downloaded, I want the server to detect that the download is finished and delete the zip file.

1- How do I expose the file in node js? Should the system put it in public folder? That means it will be security risk and anyone can read it.How can I link to a file & make it downloadable which is not in public folder?
2- How do I detect that the download is finished? Should I run a cron job to delete the files without worrying about the download progress?

Comment: How are you generating the zip file? Can you not simply respond to the request to generate the zip file *with* the zip file. It will be far simpler to secure the zip file and know when to delete it if you do it that way.

Comment: I generate the zip file by calling the zip command line tool built in to the operating system.

Answer (score 1):

A few remarks that should help you:

1. If you are creating temporary files, a good practice is to create **signed** URLs. Those are URLS that contain specific token that is valid for a limited amount of time. Implementation is trivial - generate the file .zip and token, set timestamp preferably in the DB and construct signed link with token. If the file is not downloaded by client in a given amount of time, it is invalid.
2. Zip file should have unique name, preferably some random one (if it's not a problem, you could still use header called `Content-Disposition` to decide on its name during download). You store it in the TEMP dir inside your project.
3. After user clicks previously generated signed link with token that relates to that file, you start download (streaming). After streaming is complete (refer to NodeJS streams lib), you just delete the file.

And on the client side:

1. You create a button that leads to endpoint on server (triggers AJAX call or whatever). After clicking, you run mentioned above logic on server.
2. In return, user client gets generated link (leading to ANOTHER endpoint that handles those **signed** links only) that has to be followed to download the file
3. Using any kind of DOM manipulation, you create hidden `<a/>` tag with `href` leading to this link and then you trigger automatic click of this link in the JS code. Preferably, if you support new browsers, it's a good idea to add `download` attribute to it.

**DO NOT:**

- put the file in the public folder. Create endpoint that will stream its contents to the client. Create just some temp dir for it.
- run the CRON job for deleting the files. Or run it only if something fails, to clean old files. File should be deleted after it's downloaded (which you will know, as when your stream is closed, you will get a proper event).

**IMPLEMENTATION SUGGESTIONS**

1. Create two endpoints on the server (using Express or whatever framework for routing). One for requesting the file (that starts generation process) and another one for downloading it.
2. After the generation process is finished, store the .zip inside e.g. `temp` catalog and create token for it.
3. Store set of data like this in the DB for EVERY download:

   - zip file name
   - token (e.g. generated random hash)
   - timestamp of the generation
4. Pass the new link to the client (for the second endpoint that is used for download process). Client should initialise the download automatically without human interaction, as suggested above
5. When link is "clicked" by the code, your server receives another request on second endpoint and then:

   - checks if the token is still valid (e.g. for 30 seconds).
   - if not: 403 or 404
   - if yes: start streaming the data (create file stream and stream it to the client)
   - when streaming back, include proper headers with response, e.g. file name that client should see (this will obscure your internal file names from `temp` catalog), using `Content-Disposition`
6. After streaming is complete, delete the file
7. Create CRON job that will run e.g. once a day, ask the DB for ALL the files that have invalid tokens (expired ones) and will try to delete them, if they exist (but this should not be a common scenario, if you delete them properly when the streaming is finished).